# Neo4j OGM & Multiple similar classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4j ogm to map many (over 20) similar classes into neo4j db which are different in just
relationship name, name and direction.
Each class implements the "Classification" interface with just one method which is the same 
in every class (consist on adding relation into collection of node)

Example node:

```
@NodeEntity
public class ExampleClass implements Classification {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "EXAMPLE_1", direction = "OUTGOING")
    private Set<Species> classification = new HashSet<>();


    public ExampleClass (){}
    public ExampleClass (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Species> getClassification(){
        return classification;
    }
    @Override
    public void specifiedAs(Species species){
        classification.add(species);
    }
```

and analogously:

```
@NodeEntity
public class ExampleClass2 implements Classification {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "EXAMPLE_2", direction = "OUTGOING")
    private Set<Species> classification = new HashSet<>();

    public ExampleClass2 (){}
    public ExampleClass2 (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Species> getClassification(){
        return classification;
    }
    @Override
    public void specifiedAs(Species species){
        classification.add(species);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for possibility to reduce count of those similar classes 
and create... maybe one generic class in which I can define label,property name and realtionship type also.
I prefer still using spring-data and Neo4j OGM.

Answer (score 1):

You could improve this by introducing an super class containing all the common properties, and just have the specific relationships in your `ExampleClassXXX` classes.

Note that the relationship types cannot be dynamic, so you cannot have just a generic class by itself.